# how to change font style of cell in rdlc report?

Tags: c#, rdlc

how to change font style of cell in rdlc report .
I want to change only those font in cell that start with "G".
I already tried but I can't solve this.

Comment: Show me what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Select the complete row from left bar and you can change the font there. It will change the font of all the cells in that row. Some more details [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1473013.aspx?dyanamically+change+font+size+in+Report+rdlc+urgent+) and from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252080%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :

Right click textbox -> Properties -> Font -> Click on fx -> And then give this expression `=IIf(Fields!MyField.Value.ToString().StartsWith("G"), "Arial","Cooper Black")`

Comment: i have a one column that,s name is GTotal and in this column have for ex. five value like 10.0,15.5,2.5,G 30.5,23.5.so i want to change font style of "G 30.5" in bold.i tried code you give me but it change font of all value but not change start with G.

Comment: What is the expression you use? Show me?

Comment: i use this expression.
    =iif(Fields!GTotal.value.Tostring().StartWith("G"),"Arial","Cooper Black").
but not work

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you share a screenshot or something?

Comment: my screenshot not posted because it ask 10 reputation